# How to run nest-prom on different port?

Tags: nestjs, prometheus

I am using [@digikare/nestjs-prom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digikare/nestjs-prom) to collect metrics in my service. I would like to expose the /metrics endpoint only on port 9090 and not on the main port.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use a different module. That module also provides a tutorial on how to do it correctly.

https://github.com/willsoto/nestjs-prometheus/issues/938

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this package just adds an endpoint, so if you want `/metrics` to be on port 9090 you'd either need to run the app on that port, or make a reverse proxy run on port 9090 and forward on `/metrics` to your main application.

Comment: The purpose of putting it on another port is that it can not accidentally leak to the internet. So I would not want the endpoint to be available on the normal service port.

Comment: I understand the intent, but I'm also letting you know that due to how the library is set up, you can't just run an endpoint on a different port. You could set up a guard around that endpoint though (or possibly a middleware) to ensure it can't be normally accessed